# Ideal way of calling multiple route at once using Node js and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, routes

What is the ideal way of calling multiple routes or rendering multiple routes at once in node and express ? For example If I have 2 routes which is     app.get('/', routes.views.index); and app.all('/header',routes.views.header); When app.get('/', routes.views.index); renders then it should also render app.all('/header', routes.views.header);. Is promise a good solution to that ?or array of callbacks ? any Idea? . Or Async ? . Wanted to render index route and header route at once.   When index route is called I also want to include header cause header routes contains the data for the header
    and the header is extended/included on index so both should render

## Route Bindings

```
exports = module.exports = function (app) {

    app.get('/', routes.views.index);
    app.get('/blog/:category?', routes.views.blog);
    app.get('/blog/post/:post', routes.views.post);
    app.get('/gallery', routes.views.gallery);
    app.all('/contact', routes.views.contact);


    app.all('/header', routes.views.header);



    //Views for vehicle
    app.get('/searchnew/:category?', routes.views.vehicle)

    app.get('/:parent/:slug?', routes.views.pages);

    // NOTE: To protect a route so that only admins can see it, use the requireUser middleware:
    // app.get('/protected', middleware.requireUser, routes.views.protected);

    // User
    app.get('/api/user', [keystone.middleware.api, keystone.middleware.cors], routes.api.user.list);
    app.get('/api/user/:id', [keystone.middleware.api, keystone.middleware.cors], routes.api.user.get);
    app.post('/api/user', [keystone.middleware.api, keystone.middleware.cors], routes.api.user.create);
    app.put('/api/user/:id', [keystone.middleware.api, keystone.middleware.cors], routes.api.user.update);
    app.delete('/api/user/:id', [keystone.middleware.api, keystone.middleware.cors], routes.api.user.remove);

    //Vehicle API





};
```

Comment: What does `routes.views.header` and `routes.views.index` look like? This is a pretty weird requirement. Normally, only one router is invoked, and that router handler will compose 2 different view components

Comment: Is using  router handler would be a solution to this ?

Comment: how about using router handler to the issue?

Comment: Well, as long as you can compose 2 view component template, it's fine.

Comment: I have 2 view component templates

Comment: I was able to compose it

Comment: is An array of callback functions a good way to handle this ?

Comment: No. What render engine are you using? ejs? Please read that view engine document first.

Comment: nunjucks Sir , i am using nunjucks

Comment: Ah, I'm using nunjucks too. I'll provide an answer soon.

Comment: Okay,2 thanks , .....

Comment: are you also familiar with keystone js ?

Comment: I've provided my answer. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with keystone.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: OP want to send 2 HTTP requests, one to get the page (call `/` router), and another to call `/header` router to render dynamic content.

In this case, you can:

Step 1. Open home page (send `GET /` HTTP request). In this step, router `/` is called.

Step 2. Once the home page is completely loaded(e.g. listen `window.onload` event),  send an Ajax request to get dynamic header content (`GET /header`). In this step, router `/header` is called.

Step 3. After the dynamic header content is returned, render that content in current page, using JavaScript.

---

Old answer:

You don't need to "call multiple routes". What you need is "call one route" (send one HTTP GET request), and compose multiple view components in render engine (e.g. nunjucks).

For example, when HTTP request is `GET /`, the server will receive this request, trying to render corresponding template (`index.html` for example). If "header" component need to be embedded, it can be composed using render engine technology:

```
// In router file, render template for "/"
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});

// In "index" template file, embed "header" component
<!doctype html>
<html lang="zh-CN">
...
{% include "header.html" %}
...
</html>
```

Comment: How will i be able to execute the header route ?   app.all('/header', routes.views.header); , cause this route calls another view that renders the script.

Comment: cause this is how it works 

app.all('/header', routes.views.header); ---- > goes to routes -> views -> header.js and then header.js renders the html using view.render('./layouts/header');

Comment: If you are visiting home page ('/') which contains "header", then you don't need to access header route.

Comment: so it means if i am going to include {% include "header.html" %} to a page then it will call and execute this route   app.all('/header', routes.views.header);

Comment: No. It won't execute the header router, but it will import the header view component.

Comment: I have no problem in executing the header components , what i want to render is this route   app.all('/header', routes.views.header); cause the data from the header is dynamic which is from this route app.all('/header', routes.views.header); if this route cannot be called then there is no data on the header

Comment: the menu from the header is dynamic which is from header route sir

Comment: Ah, I understand. What you need is sending Ajax request. I'll update my answer.

Comment: That is why i need to render the route without user clicking anything to call the routes it should be automatically called once the page renders cause it is header

Comment: is ajax the only clean way to do that ?

Comment: I think ajax is the best way to do. Also, I've updated my answer.

Comment: that would already be client side rendering if i use ajax , is there no server side way of rendering this or doing this ?

Comment: I don't think that's possible -- if 2 router handler is called for 1 HTTP request, 2 http responses will be attempted to return (using `res.send()` or `res.render()` etc.). Express will detect this scenario and throw error. After all, it violates HTTP protocol.

Comment: Then i should be calling ajax request on my header then so that everytime header was called it will call the route and will load the data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196248/discussion-between-shaochuancs-and-mr-rajiv-kumar).

Comment: are you still there?

Comment: Kumar, please check my message in chat